# Can I hide/remove the UI from Karma result?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am using angular 6.1.6 and really new to Karma. When I run `ng test`,
the result shows some elements ([please see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQV89.png)). Can I hide them/remove from my testing result?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your test is adding things directly to the dom, which is non-standard (though there are some instances where this is a good idea). In general, your tests should not attach any dom to the document object (eg- by calling `document.querySelector('#foo').appendChild(...)`. If you create dom elements, you should avoid attaching them to the document.

If you do attach dom elements to the document, the simplest way to remove them is in an `afterEach` block in your `describe` spec, like this:

```
afterEach(() => document.querySelector('#my-element').remove());
```

Answer (score 5):

I got another answer.

Putting this in the beforeEach function works well

`fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.style.visibility = "hidden";`

and it would hide the flashing component when testing.

Comment: `fixture.nativeElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';` is enough